# Сложность алгоритма, содержащего рандомную операцию

Tags: алгоритм, сложность, асимптотика

Для всякого ли алгоритма можно оценить сложность при помощи О нотации?

Допустим, я имею массив чисел и хочу вытащить оттуда любое, условно, четное. Но перебирать их буду не по-порядку, а рандомно, в бесконечном цикле, пока не найду нужное. Конечно, это очень кривой подход (в плане доступа к кэшам, например), но можно ли оценить его **алгоритмическую** сложность?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, можно. Следует оценивать с учётом вероятности.

Например, сложность [bogosort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) оценивается как
[image: O(n * n!)]

> я имею массив чисел и хочу вытащить оттуда любое, условно, четное. Но перебирать их буду не по-порядку, а рандомно, в бесконечном цикле, пока не найду нужное.

Если в массиве около половины чисел чётные, то O(1).
Если только одно число чётное, то O(n) с жирненькой константой.
Если ни одного, то алгоритм вообще не завершится.

Если рассматривать случайный (равномерный) массив, то, вероятно, будет сводиться к O(1) - как доступ по ключу хэш-таблицы.

PS: Провёл эксперимент для случая с единственным искомым числом (результат смотреть в реальной консоли, открытой до запуска сниппета; при запуске браузер может зависнуть на несколько секунд):

```js
function go(n) {
  while (Math.random() * n | 0);
}

var res = [];

function check(n) {
  var t = performance.now();
  go(1<<n);
  t = performance.now() - t;
  (res[n] = res[n] || []).push(t);
}

for (var q=1; q<14; ++q)
  for (var w=0; w<10000; ++w)
    check(q);

function stat(a) {
  return { 
    min: Math.min(...a),
    max: Math.max(...a),
    sum: a.reduce((x,y) => x+y)
  }
}

console.table(res.map(stat));
```

[image: Скриншот результата]

При удвоении длины время увеличивается вдвое, т. е. действительно O(n).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А разве О нотация оценивает не наихудший случай?

Comment: @TheSN, не всегда. Мы же говорим про хэш-таблицу O(1), хотя худший случай там O(n). B про быструю сортировку O(n*lb(n)), хотя худший случай O(n*n). Только вот я пытаюсь понять, правильно ли я оценил выбор чётных чисел. Возможно, там n^2. Хочу эксперимент сделать.

Comment: imho в среднем за n/2 одно четное должно ловится

Comment: @TheSN, добавил эксперимент.

Comment: @avp, всё, я вспомнил, откуда в bogosort умножение на n. Там же для каждой перестановки делается проверка за n шагов. Так что всё верно, O(n) и никаких O(n^2).