# Как классифицировать степенную функцию по точкам?

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, math

Есть набор точек на плоскости, (для простоты допустим, что это точки с координатами по x от 0 до n)

Например, `a = [0, 1, 4, 9]`, где `a[x] = f(x)`.
Нужно написать алгоритм, который классифицировал бы функцию графика, построенного по этим точкам. 
Классификатор линейной функции я уже написал:

```
def is_linear(a):
    difference = a[1] - a[0]
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        if a[i + 1] - a[i] != difference:
            return False

    return True
```

Теперь нужен классификатор степенной функции (ну или хотя бы квадратичной вида y = ax^2 + bx + c)

Comment: в логарифмическом масштабе степенная функция будет линейная. Можно найти наиболее подходящие коэффициенты используя метод наименьших квадратов ([`numpy.polyfit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)). [Примеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706335/23044).

Comment: @jfs, как-то сложно, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy в чём сложности? вызвать функцию? `polyfit(log(x[x>0]), log(a[x>0]), def=1)`

Comment: @jfs, а чего тогда не ответом?

Comment: @Qwertiy: детали вопроса не ясны (целые/не целые, точные значения/с шумом, допустимые диапазоны аргументов, функций, какой контекст). Автору polyfit() может и не нужен, но будущим посетителям с похожей проблемой из поисковика может пригодиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Производная от квадратичной функции будет линейной. А от кубической - квадратичной. И так далее. Производная представляется разностью соседних элементов. Поскольку разностей на 1 меньше, чем точек, рано или поздно массив сведётся к 2 элементам, которые гарантированно образуют линейную функцию, т. е. алгоритм конечен. Замечу, что такой многочлен называется интерполяционным - по любым n точкам можно построить многочлен степени n-1, проходящий через все эти точки.

Вот код на js, на питон легко переписать должно быть:

```js
var EPS = 1e-6

function isConstant(a) {
  if (a.length <= 1) {
    return true
  }
  
  for (var q=1; q<a.length; ++q) {
    if (Math.abs(a[q]-a[q-1]) > EPS) {
      return false
    }
  }
  
  return true
}

function getDegree(a) {
  for (var d=0; ; ++d) {
    if (isConstant(a)) {
      return d
    }
    
    for (var q=1; q<a.length; ++q) {
      a[q-1] = a[q] - a[q-1]
    }
    
    --a.length
  }
}

console.log(getDegree([1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(x => 2*x**3 + x**2 - 12*x + 7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется очень похожим на вашу задачу, ключевое слово - "метод наименьших квадратов"  http://www.michurin.net/computer-science/scipy/scipy_least_squares.html