# Вычисление производной в C++

Tags: c++

Возможно ли в C++ вычислять производную не конкретно по функции, а по массиву значений этой функции?
К примеру, задается массив значений X с интервалом от a до b; далее этот массив загоняется в заданную заранее функцию Y(X) -> получается второй массив. 
И элементы второго массива уже загоняются в формулы вычисления производных 2-го и 4- порядков, тем самым получая еще 2 массива.

Кто шарит, можете помочь с реализацией:)

Comment: Что такое производная для массива? dy/dx для соседних точек?

Comment: Можно, как и на любом другом языке. Подробнее тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737551/178988

Comment: @vp_arth, ну да. Так обычно и делают. Кстати, вот [википедия](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), правда, там что-то другое написали.